# How to allow all file types for upload in php?

Tags: php, file-upload

Hello I have a php script that is used to allow file uploads. The script has an array that with allowable file types.

```
      $fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'xlsx')
```

Because the form is behind a log in area for my client, he is requesting to allow ALL file types, rather than to be restricted to files in the array. Although I have already explained to the client that it would be better to limit the files, he insist on having it open.

Is there a way to allow for any file type in an array?

Full Script

```
      $uploadDir = '/uploads/';

      // Set the allowed file extensions
      $fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'xlsx', 'cad', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'pps', 'ppsx', 'odt', 'xls', 'xlsx', '.mp3', 'm4a', 'ogg', 'wav', 'mp4', 'm4v', 'mov', 'wmv' ); // Allowed file extensions

     $verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

    if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;
$targetFile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the filetype
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
if (in_array(strtolower($fileParts['extension']), $fileTypes)) {

    // Save the file
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    echo 1;

  } else {

    // The file type wasn't allowed
    echo 'Invalid file type.';

  }
    }
```

Comment: yes - just don't do the filtering.

Comment: can you show us the complete script?

Comment: Oh sorry, OK I updated this with the script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't do the filtering.

```
<?php
$uploadDir = '/uploads/';

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;
    $targetFile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Save the file
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    echo 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the file type validation and upload all

```
//if (in_array(strtolower($fileParts['extension']), $fileTypes)) {

    // Save the file
   if( move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile)){
    echo 1;
    else{
    echo 'An error occurred ';
    }

//  } else {

    // The file type wasn't allowed
   // echo 'Invalid file type.';

  //}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rather following code

```
<?php
$uploadDir = '/uploads/';

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;
    $targetFile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Save the file
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    echo 1;

}

?>
```